# SQL needed for getting latest records based on Status?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table TRX which has multiple values TRXID for a given SRCID sample data set shown below.

```
TRXID       STATUS  TIMESTAMP                           SRCID
839         EN      30-OCT-14 11.08.13.597000000 AM     B0D35D0168G
1189        MO      30-OCT-14 11.13.19.554000000 AM     B0D35D0168G
1549        CA      30-OCT-14 12.13.42.246000000 PM     B0D35D0168G

1666        EN      30-OCT-14 02.43.22.271000000 PM     A0D77E2168G
2221        CA      30-OCT-14 05.49.16.712000000 PM     A0D77E2168G
2244        EN      31-OCT-14 11.21.18.146000000 AM     A0D77E2168G  ...
```

I want to get all SRCID which have latest status = 'CA' based on latest TIMESTAMP only.
so e.g if we ran the query for above data set we would only get 'B0D35D0168G' as a result.

Comment: Is the combination of CA and Timestamp unique?  If so, you will always only get one record and you can use SELECT TOP 1 for your query

Comment: @MikeTWebb: That only works if you have *one group.*

Comment: @Robert...really?  In the above table, using SELECT TOP 1 WHERE STATUS='CA' ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC gets the appropriate record

Comment: `TOP` is SQL Server syntax ... not Oracle. Also, this solution `SELECT TOP 1 WHERE STATUS='CA' ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC` won't work - it will get the last timestamp where status = 'CA', not the record where the last status, ordered by timestamp, is = 'CA'.

Comment: @David...typo.  The query should read SELECT TOP 1 * WHERE STATUS='CA' ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC.  But I get what you're saying now.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work in Oracle:

```
SELECT srcid FROM (
    SELECT srcid, status, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY srcid ORDER BY timestamp DESC ) AS rn
      FROM trx
) WHERE status = 'CA' AND rn = 1;
```

It will work if you need to retrieve additional columns as well (e.g., if you need to know what the last value of `timestamp` is).

```
SELECT trxid, srcid, timestamp FROM (
    SELECT trxid, srcid, timestamp, status, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY srcid ORDER BY timestamp DESC ) AS rn
      FROM trx
) WHERE status = 'CA' AND rn = 1;
```

Comment: The inner query will take too long to execute can i add a date range to the clause e.g date between 20150112 and 20150113 ?. for the TRX table as i have a date column there as well

Comment: @RobertHarvey, `TOP` is particular to SQL Server so that would actually be more proprietary. Window functions like `ROW_NUMBER()` are standard SQL.

Comment: @SHinny, yes, of course you can add a date range to the inner query: `WHERE datecolumn BETWEEN TO_DATE('20150112', 'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20150113', 'YYYYMMDD')` -- assuming your date column is of type `DATE`.

Comment: @DavidFaber thanks for the solution, this was one tough cookie :)

Comment: @DavidFaber: Withdrawn.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "most recent" pattern I've used quite successfully for several years now. If the key and date field form an index, it is really fast.

```
select  *
from    trx t1
where   t1.status = 'CA'
   and  t1.timestamp =(
      select  Max( timestamp )
      from    trx
      where   status = t1.status
         and  timestamp <= SysDate );
```

The last line of the subquery may be omitted if future dates are not possible. Either way, the query should perform only index seeks.

Comment: The above query is taking very long to execute and not getting anywhere.\

Comment: Of course it works. Proof: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05d4e/1/0 However, according to your description ("all SRCID which have latest status = 'CA' based on latest TIMESTAMP") the correct row would be trxid = 2221 not 1549 as the timestamp is later in the afternoon. If what you want is the *earliest* occurrence, then change the Max to Min. As far as taking a long time, only you can solve that. The fiddle table is very small with the 6 sample rows you gave, so I didn't create any indexes. Is yours a large table? Do you have an index on (status, timestamp)?